# Is WPF Decorator class useful?

Tags: .net, wpf, decorator

I need to create control to draw border around its child. So, I have created class and derived it from Decorator:

```
class RoundedBoxDecorator : Decorator
{
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        //some source
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        //some source
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I have some doubts about using Decorator as ancestor. I have found in MSDN that there are no special methods or properties in it, only derived from its ancestors (UIElement or FrameworkElement). ArrangeOverride and OnRender are also derived.

So, what for Decorator class was designed and does it makes sense to use it? Or I can derive from FrameworkElement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Besides what it inherits from `FrameworkElement`, the `Decorator` class implements a `Child` property (of type `UIElement`), as well as implementing the `IAddChild` interface. Thus `Decorator` is the most primitive element that can contain another element.

Is there a reason you were not able to use a `Border` element (which inherits from `Decorator`) to create the border around the child element?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need some special border, so I decided to implement my own Decorator.

Comment: @darja If it is a border I'd derive from `Border`, at least to make the semantic choice clear. I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but `RoundedBoxDecorator` sounds a bit like a workaround for `Border.CornerRadius`.